# How to retrieve only from the current user without showing other user FirebaseRecyclerOption

Tags: firebase, android-recyclerview

I need to know how to display the current user "sections" in a recycler view but only the current user data only. Thank you all.

[This is my actual list that display all the user but i only need the current user to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOdgM.jpg)

`User`
[Database user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBVtg.png)
`Reference`
[Firebase Recycler View Option reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/55qdo.png)
`View Holder`
[My View Holder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoUL2.png)
`Model User`
[My ModelUser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZLT4.png)

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up. Also see: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @. Besides that, what exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors?